# How to call a backbone view function from another view in separate files

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

I have two backbone views defined in two separate files namely: 
 LandingView.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'text!templates/landing/landingTemplate.html',
    'text!templates/invitations/invitationsTemplate.html',
    'views/invitations/InvitationsView',
], function ($, _, Backbone, Marionette, landingTemplate, invitationsTemplate, InvitationsView) {
var LandingView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $("#landing"),
        id : 'landing',
        transition : 'slide',

        initialize : function () {              
            this.GetNotificationsCounts();
        },
        events : {
            'click #invitations' : 'onInvitations',

        },
        render : function () { 
            var that = this;
            $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
            $('.menu li a[href="#"]').parent().addClass('active');

            this.$el.html(landingTemplate);

        },
        cleanup: function() { 
            this.undelegateEvents();
            $(this.el).empty();
        },
        onInvitations : function () { 

            //do something
        },

        GetProfile: function (userLogin) {
               // do something
        },


        GetNotificationsCounts: function () {
               // do something

        },

        formatAccountName: function () {
             //do something
        }


    });

return LandingView; });
```

Then there is another file InvitationsView.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'views/landing/LandingView',
    'text!templates/invitations/invitationsTemplate.html',
], function ($, _, Backbone, Marionette, LandingView, invitationsTemplate ) {


var InvitationsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $("#invitations"),
        id : 'invitations',
        transition : 'slide',

        initialize : function () { debugger;

            this.$el.attr('data-transition', this.transition);
            this.currentUserLogin = currentUserLogin;
            var that = this;

        },
        events : {

        },
        render : function () { debugger;
            $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
            $('.menu li a[href="#"]').parent().addClass('active');

            this.GetUserInvitationDetails();

             this.$el.html(invitationsTemplate);

        },
        cleanup: function() { 
            this.undelegateEvents();
            $(this.el).empty();
        },

        GetUserInvitationDetails: function () {

            var landingView =  new LandingView();
            currentUserName= landingView.formatAccountName();
            curUser = currentUserName.replace("\\", "^").replace("^", "%5E");

            var profilemsg = landingView.GetProfile(currentUserName);

        },

    });

return InvitationsView;});
```

Now I need to call the formatAccountName and GetProfile functions defined in the first JS to the second JS. I am unable to do that. I get errors. 
When I try

> var landingView =  new LandingView();
>                   currentUserName= landingView.formatAccountName();

This also fails. Can somebody help me in this regard and tell me how can I achieve this

Comment: can you show the error message?

Comment: Why is a utility function embedded in one particular view? It would make more sense to collect the utility functions in a library and pull them in anywhere that needs them. You could even set them up as mixins if that made more sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current approach of calling the `formatAccountName` method works.  The following jsfiddle shows this:

http://jsfiddle.net/v4h11qac/

The problem is likely caused by another error that has not been handled correctly, resulting in the code not being run.  You should fix the existing errors and the method call should work as expected.

**Orignal Answer:**

You could call the method directly on the prototype object:

```
LandingView.prototype.formatAccountName();
```

If you need to pass through a new context you can use the `call` or `apply` method as below:

```
LandingView.prototype.formatAccountName.call(context);
```

A better approach might involve creating a helper module that can be shared by both views.

```
var viewHelpers = {
    formatAccountName: function(account) {
        // ...
    }
};

var ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var formattedName = viewHelpers.formatAccountName(this.model);
        // ...
    }
};


var ViewTwo = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var formattedName = viewHelpers.formatAccountName(this.model);
        // ...
    }
};
```

You could also use a system bus, however that may be a little too heavy for such a use case.  If you want to take a look at that path, then [Backbone.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio#user-content-backboneradiorequests) provides a request/response pattern which could be used to fulfill this requirement.

Comment: Thanks Karl for the answer. I have a question on this, As I told both my view are in separate files, so in such a scenario will the approach work ? I am already using define to require all the required js in all my views. Please inform.

Comment: Yes, just add the helper module as a dependency in the modules that use it.  I've also updated my answer to include an explanation for the original problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a global event dispatcher that you declare in some kind of main-js-file like this:

```
var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Then in your view, listen for an event and run function.

```
vent.on('your:event',this.function_to_run_from_other_view,this);
```

Dispatch the event like this from the other view.

```
vent.trigger('your:event',args)
```

Comment: This is generally used when one view needs to respond to changes in another view, not for access utility functions. How would you get the return value from `formatAccountName` from an event?

Comment: Actually i had that in mind. In this case there is no return so it will probably do the work. BUT, if you have a better approach in mind (which i think) it would be great to see. Fact is that i've myself had this problem couple of times without solving it in a way that had been clean enough IMO.

Comment: My suggestion is up in [my comment on the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861006/how-to-call-a-backbone-view-function-from-another-view-in-separate-files/26861177#comment42300685_26861006), I don't have time to flesh it out right now.